# Get employees who worked in more than one department with SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, count, join

I'm trying to figure out a query which shows the names of the employees who worked in more than 2 departments along with their wage and contact details. I have two tables employees and department. Both of these having the EmployeeName field. I know we have to use the Count function but don't really know how to create the query.

here the tablename and Fields:

- `Employee` (employeeName, wage, contactNo)
- `Department` (employeeName, departmentNo, hours, startDate)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You SQL query would be the following

```
  SELECT e.employeeName, count(departmentNo) FROM Employee e 
  INNER JOIN Department d ON e.employeeName=d.employeeName 
  GROUP BY e.employeeName 
  HAVING COUNT(departmentNo)>2
```

Comment: @GoldFish Welcome to SO :)

Comment: must be >= 2 or it need at least 3, EDIT: title mismatch

Comment: @ImreL Does it >= 2? The OP says "more than 2" - so it is >2

Comment: yea it should be more than 2 so >2 is working perfectly ..but it's showing me some error when i try to show other fields with employeeName

Comment: I have now figured out that problem too..everything working perfectly..Thankyou guys for your all kind help

Comment: @GoldFish each field you add to employeeName should be added to GROUP BY part also. Or you can SELECT using nested SELECT with IN statement.

Comment: I have already figured out that problem too..thanks though :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use following query:

```
SELECT e.employeeName, count(d.departmentname) 
FROM Employee e, Department d  
where e.deptid=d.deptid 
GROUP BY e.employeeName 
HAVING COUNT(e.deptid)>=2
```